# Merge project from other branch git

Tags: git, merge, branch

We are working on two (maven) projects, `project-a`  and `project-b` on a git repository.

I have created a branch `branch-a` on which I have been working on `project-a` and now I want to align the code of `project-b`, from the branch `main`, basically overwriting any modification that I might have inadvertently made on it, but keeping my version of `project-a`.

Here is a visual explanation:

```
Current situation                What I want

main                             main                        (untoched)
  |___project-a-v1.0               |___project-a-v1.0
  |___project-b-v5.0               |___project-b-v5.0

branch-a                         branch-a                    (project-b is aligned 
  |___project-a-v2.0               |___project-a-v2.0        with main)
  |___project-b-v2.0               |___project-b-v5.0
```

What is the correct procedure on Git (or EGit) to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What means "to align the code"?

Comment: If you have two separate project, it's best to have not two branches, but two repositories. I recommend you to consider splitting the repository in two. Here's some explanation to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293926/separate-branches-or-git-projects

Comment: What do you have in this main branch?

Comment: I added a visual explanation, i hope is more clear. @NickVolynkin I am studying repositories but this is the current setup in my company so I still have to perform this merge :)

Comment: Some more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30630904/2790048 =)